# Como configurar corretamente rotas no angular 4 com lazy loading

Tags: angular

**meu link de listar o cliente simplement nao funciona , queria saber o por que O QUE EU TERIA QUE FAZER PRA CHAMAR A ROTA /listaclientes e nao clientes/listaclientes**

1 - ClienteRoutingModule 
2 - AppRoutingModule 
3-  routerlink

```js
import { LoginGuard } from './login/login.guard';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'clientes', loadChildren: 'app/clientes/cliente.module#ClienteModule' },
  
 // { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
import { ClientesPedidosComponent } from './clientes-pedidos/clientes-pedidos.component';
import { LoginGuard } from './../login/login.guard';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientesListaComponent } from './clientes-lista/clientes-lista.component';
import { ClientesComponent } from './clientes.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    //path: 'clientes' using lazyloading,
    path: '',
    component: ClientesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'listaclientes', component: ClientesListaComponent },
      { path: 'lista-pedidos', component: ClientesPedidosComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: ClientesComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ClienteRoutingModule { }
```

```html
<li><a routerLink="/listaclientes"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>Lista de Clientes</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Com a configuração atual que você esta fazendo você deve acessar `/clientes/listaclientes`.

Por que disso?

R: Você esta registrando o path `/listaclientes` dentro do módulo `ClienteRoutingModule` que é carregado dinamicamente junto do `ClienteModule`. Então por padrão, seu path `/listaclientes` é um path filho do path `/clientes` que carrega o módulo.

Como chamar apenas `/listaclientes`?

R: Você tem que registrar o path no módulo principal de rotas, o `AppRoutingModule`.

E não, não tem como você registrar um path em um Módulo filho e acessá-lo sem utilizar o path de seu pai antes dele.

Se você utilizar hierarquia de módulos, vai ter de usar hierarquia de paths.

Comment: Agora eu entendi o lance dessa budega... acontece que ' ' rota vazia eu estou chamando o cadastrocomponent e nao a lista...

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer funcionar da forma como você quer, com lazy loading, teria que criar um módulo para cada sub rota.

Acontece que para usar lazy loading, você tem que declarar um módulo com rota no app.module, ao declarar esse módulo, obrigatoriamente você deve declarar um path, esse path já vai gerar um segmento de URL e todas as sub rotas dentro desse "lazy loaded" module estarão sob o segmento do módulo inicial, no seu caso "clientes".

Se você quiser uma gambiarra, pode criar um path no app.module redirecionando para uma sub rota do módulo clientes:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
    {path: 'listaclientes', redirectTo: 'clientes/listaclientes'}, 
];
```

Comment: pelo video da loiane ela manda retirar qualquer declaração dentro de app.module e foi isso que fiz

Comment: sim, é bom vc tirar tudo de lá mesmo, usando lazy-loading, mas pra usar lazy-loading, obrigatoriamente vc tem que passar um caminho/rota/path apontando pra um módulo, sendo assim, ou você cria um módulo para cada sub rota, ou fica com o path /clientes/

Comment: uma gambiarra que você pode fazer, é declarar uma rota no app.module redirecionando para a rota dentro do módulo clientes, mas não acho interessante, inclusive não vejo porque vc não vai querer esse segmento /clientes na url, já que vai padronizar suas rotas.